# Syncronizing program with updated input file

Tags: c++, linux, stat

I am working on 64bit Ubuntu 16.04 and in my code trying to reflect any updates on my input file into my program. I wrote this test code which seems to be working; when I make changes on input file and save the file,  I can see the updates on console usually. But some times it updates only after 3-5 times saving and does not updates even I keep saving changes multiple times. Am I using something wrong, what might be causing this behavior? Is there a better way of doing this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define INFILE "test.txt"

using namespace std;

__time_t getFileModifyTime(char *filePath)
{
    struct stat attrib;
    stat(filePath, &attrib);
    __time_t date = attrib.st_mtime ;
    return date;
}

int main(){

    ifstream infile;
    infile.open (INFILE);
    string currentLine;

    __time_t lastUpdateTime = 0;    

    while(true)     // start an infinite loop
    {
        if(lastUpdateTime != getFileModifyTime(INFILE)) {

            cout << "last update time  : " << lastUpdateTime << endl;
            cout << "modification time : " << getFileModifyTime(INFILE) << endl;

            infile.close();
            infile.open (INFILE);

            while (getline(infile, currentLine)) {
                cout << currentLine << endl;
            }    
        }
        lastUpdateTime = getFileModifyTime(INFILE);
    }
    // if a miracle happens
    return  0;
}
```

Comment: Did you retry my original suggestion?

Comment: @JakeFreeman yes but it did not worked for me, my compiler did not like auto types and mod_time_first == getLastTime() was taking the same value and not updating somehow so I modified the behavior a little

Comment: Why are you keeping the file open while its checking?

Comment: Not that I like `auto` but: "my compiler did not like auto types" What compiler you are using? Not g++ (aka gcc)? If you used g++: Did you `g++ -std=c++11`?

Comment: @JakeFreeman  it was not working if I use rewind()  or  inputFile.clear();
inputFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);   so I tried this workaround...

Comment: @Scheff I am workin on CLion with C++11, not compiling from console so I did not tried that, but thats not my actual problem

Comment: AFAIK, CLion is the IDE only. Even on Windows, it is shipped with gcc (mingw in that case). As you tagged [tag:linux], I would be surprised if you don't use gcc/g++. Hence my confusion...

Answer (score 0):

> Am I using something wrong, what might be causing this behavior?

Yes - you failed to check the return value of `stat()`. Some popular editors, when you *save the file*, rename it to a backup name and write a new file (the backup then may even be removed and unseen), so for some time in-between the `INFILE` name doesn't exist and `stat()` fails, but still the uninitialized `attrib.st_mtime` is used, causing the behaviour to be not defined. For a minimal change, print the error to see if this occurs and make `attrib` defined `static`:

```
    static struct stat attrib;
    if (stat(filePath, &attrib) < 0) perror(INFILE);
```

That said, the reason that *some times it updates only after 3-5 times saving* is a different one:

```
        if(lastUpdateTime != getFileModifyTime(INFILE)) {
            …
        }
        lastUpdateTime = getFileModifyTime(INFILE);
```

If the file is modified between the two `getFileModifyTime()` calls, the change goes unnoticed. For a minimal change, move the second call to the start of the `if` block:

```
        if (lastUpdateTime != getFileModifyTime(INFILE))
        {
            lastUpdateTime = getFileModifyTime(INFILE);
            …
        }
```

> Is there a better way of doing this?

Using [`inotify`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) would surely be better.